# Spout not getting acked

Tags: apache-storm

In one of our topologies containing 1 spout and 1 bolt - I had a hunch that bolts are completing fine (and acking) but spouts are still failing.

I tried to confirm this by having a TaskHook as below -

```
public class BaseHook extends BaseTaskHook {

    private Logger logger;
    private String topology;
    private String component;

    public BaseHook(String component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context) {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        this.topology = (String) conf.get("topology.name");
    }

    @Override
    public void emit(EmitInfo info) {
        log("EMITTED >> Value = " + info.values);
    }

    @Override
    public void spoutAck(SpoutAckInfo info) {
        log("ACKED >> Tuple = " + info.messageId + ", Latency = " + info.completeLatencyMs);
    }

    @Override
    public void spoutFail(SpoutFailInfo info) {
        log("FAILED >> Tuple = " + info.messageId + ", Latency = " + info.failLatencyMs);
    }

    @Override
    public void boltExecute(BoltExecuteInfo info) {
        log("EXECUTED >> Tuple = " + info.tuple.getValues() + ", Latency = " + info.executeLatencyMs);
    }

    @Override
    public void boltAck(BoltAckInfo info) {
        log("ACKED >> Tuple = " + info.tuple.getValues() + ", Latency = " + info.processLatencyMs);
    }

    @Override
    public void boltFail(BoltFailInfo info) {
        log("FAILED >> Tuple = " + info.tuple.getValues() + ", Latency = " + info.failLatencyMs);
    }

    private void log(String msg) {
        logger.info(">>>>> " + topology + " >> " + component + " >> " + msg);
    }
}
```

Turned out that my hunch is correct. The logs look something like this -

```
>>>>> TopologyX >> SpoutX >> EMITTED >> Value = [XXXXXXXXX]
>>>>> TopologyX >> BoltX >> ACKED >> Tuple = [XXXXXXXXX], Latency = 1972
>>>>> TopologyX >> BoltX >> EXECUTED >> Tuple = [XXXXXXXXX], Latency = 1973
>>>>> TopologyX >> SpoutX >> FAILED >> Tuple = XXXXXXXXX, Latency = 53913
```

ie. The Bolt is taking almost 2s (To Execute and Ack) but Spout Fail is being called at around 53s (almost twice of `topology.message.timeout.secs * 2`.

I would expect Spout Ack to be called that too within 2-3sec. Spout is non-blocking and bolts and ackers both have ample capacity to work with.

Anyone got any hints as to what might be the cause?

---

### Update

So here is what out storm cluster looked like -

- 4 Topologies

  - `T1` = S > B > B > B > Ack/Fail
  - `T2` = S > B > Ack/Fail
  - `T3` = S > B > B > Ack/Fail
  - `T4` =

    - S > B > Ack/Fail
    - S > B > Ack/Fail

So, the topology in question is `T4` ie. the one with 2 different spouts and 2 bolts. One of these flows, generally works fine (they do have different messageIds uniquely identifying tuples)

Can this be the issue?

Anyways,

- We tried reducing executors to whatever we can but that didn't improve anything in `T4`.
- We disabled all other topologies and things worked absolutely fine for `T4`
- We enabled `T1` and still things worked fine
- We enabled `T2` (and `T3` on other occasion) and `T4` started failing

Now,

- On one random occasion, `T4` even worked with T1 and T3 both enabled.
- But otherwise, every time `T2` or `T3` is enabled, `T4` breaks down.

Points to note -

- `T3` and `T4` are both quick topologies ie. their flow finishes in < 100ms
- Both, `T3` and `T4` have just 1 executor per Spout and Bolts
- Both, `T3` and `T4` have Max Tuple Pending = 1
- We want to rate limit both `T3` and `T4` (but have tried without rate limiting too)

  - Try 1: Without any limiting
  - Try 2: Sleep for 50ms before emitting
  - Try 3: Sleep for 50ms after emitting
  - Try 4: Don't sleep, but emit only if its been 50s from last emit
  - Nothing worked

---

### Additional Info based on comment

All out Spouts extend from BaseSpout class -

```
public abstract class BaseSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;

    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        context.addTaskHook(new BaseHook(this.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        try {
            this.collector = collector;
            open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error when preparing spout", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        try {
            getTuple();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (!(t instanceof FailedException)) {
                t = new FailedException("nextTuple()", t);
            }
            collector.reportError(t);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        String[] fields = getFields();
        if (fields != null) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields(fields));
        }
    }

    protected void emit(Values values, String msgId) {
        collector.emit(values, msgId);
    }

    protected abstract void open() throws Exception;

    protected abstract void getTuple() throws Exception;

    protected abstract String[] getFields();
}
```

and all out bolts extend from BaseBolt class -

```
public abstract class BaseBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

    private OutputCollector collector;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {   
        context.addTaskHook(new BaseHook(this.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        try {
            this.collector = collector;
            prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error when preparing bolt", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        try {
            process(tuple);
            collector.ack(tuple);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (!(t instanceof FailedException)) {
                t = new FailedException("execute(" + tuple + ")", t);
            }
            collector.reportError(t);
            collector.fail(tuple);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        String[] fields = getFields();
        if (fields != null) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields(fields));
        }
    }

    protected void emit(Tuple tuple, Values values) {
        collector.emit(tuple, values);
    }

    protected abstract void prepare() throws Exception;

    protected abstract void process(Tuple tuple) throws Exception;

    protected abstract String[] getFields();
}
```

So to say, there is no possibility of emitting a tuple without messageID (from spout) or unanchored tuple (from bolt)

Comment: can you place your bolt & spout code here ? I think that maybe what you see is timing issues. Are you sure anchoring is done properly ?

Comment: @Mzf - I have added our BaseSpout and BaseBolt code, in the question above. Let me know, if any more info is required.

Comment: Just a hunch, most probably there is some critical section that is not safeguarded. Usually Storm is dependable. Also the delays might be because Storm retried the tuple multiple times before failing. Could you post, in a business-agnostic way, the algorithm and data-structures you are dealing with?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem...did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: In my case, I was not receiving acks because I was using a while loop in `nextTuple()` to continuously emit. Instead, when I programmed it to emit and then leave the nextTuple function, then the ack's started coming. That's the solution. Emit and exit the nextTuple function.

Comment: @Nav, see the example `BaseSpout` class posted in the problem description... it doesn't have a loop. I was emitting only 1 tuple per `nextTuple()` call

Comment: I know. I just posted my comment in case someone else has the same problem, reaches this page and finds my info useful. Also posted here now: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2016/05/more-concepts-of-apache-storm-you-need.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue here is that the call to `Spout.nextTuple()` and `Spout.ack()` or `Spout.fail()` all happen on the same thread. If you are pulling a high volume of tuples into your topology then ack or fail messages will end up waiting to be processed by the source spout, resulting in your extended delay to ack/fail.

Also you mentioned that "sleeping" had no effect. If you mean that you called `Thread.sleep()`, in the spouts `nextTuple()` method, then this will only make things worse as you are stopping the thread that would process the ack/fails.